# How to hide div when clicked outside of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following div:

```
<div id="welcome-lightbox">
   <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

I want to hide the div when the user clicks anywhere ***BUT*** inside the div. I thought the most elegant way to do this would be stopPropagation (http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $('#welcome-lightbox').hide();
  $('#welcome-lightbox-box').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

However, this approach does not seem to work; the div still hides when clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: What I usually do is creating another element as an overlay.
And since the lightbox has a higher value of z-index - clicking the overlay means clicking outside the lightbox.

Comment: What is `#welcome-lightbox-box`, surely you just want to register the event against `#welcome-lightbox`?

Comment: Can you post your HTML. Maybe a jsFiddle too?

Comment: @OfirBaruch . If you use like that when you click on any links directly , it wont work, first the mask click will happen after that you have to click it again , End user will think why he has to click 2 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a click handler to the document, and check if the click originated from within the element by using closest() :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if (! $(e.target).closest('#welcome-lightbox').length )
        $('#welcome-lightbox').hide();
});
```

checking the `event.target` ID would close the lightbox if any element inside the lightbox, other than the lightbox itself, was clicked.

Comment: Is it a good practice to use that ? 'document' click , because when ever you click on other elements also will be triggered ?

Comment: If you want to catch a click anywhere but on a certain element, you don't have much choice

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are registering the event only after the first click on the document and it gets hidden. So move your stop propagation event registration for the specific element outside of the document's click handler.

Try:

```
$(document).click(function(){
  $('#welcome-lightbox').hide();

});
$(function(){
  $('#welcome-lightbox').click(function(event){ //Also your selector may be wrong?
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x25gS/)**

Or you could just do:

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.target.id !== 'welcome-lightbox' )
        $('#welcome-lightbox').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I extend the second example to include the same behaviour for all elements inside the parent #welcome-lightbox? (See updated DOM structure in question)

Comment: @alias51 You can do `$(document).click(function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).closest('#welcome-lightbox').length )
           $('#welcome-lightbox').hide( );
});`

Comment: @adeneo aaaha i get it... :) When i answered, the question wasn't this. When i saw OP's comment i came back to reply, but then now when i see you comment i realized something smelly, lol then saw your answer down bottom.. But then great minds think alike... !!!

Answer (score 2):

Attach an event handler above the element and then check the `target` to see if the `div` was clicked.

```
$(document).click(function(e){
    var divId = "welcome-lightbox";
    if(e.target.id != divId){
        $("#" + divId).hide();
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rG3AC/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="welcome-lightbox"></div>
```

---

```
var lightbox = document.querySelector('#welcome-lightbox');

document.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  if(e.id != lightbox.id) {
    lightbox.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by making it a 2 layer application, the outer div which spans the entire screen, like an overlay, then your inner div.  Have a click event on the inner div which stops the event propogation, but then an a click event on the outer div which closes, or hides, itself.